# Laravel: what is the best practice to show errors in a modal when save a form?

Tags: laravel, validation, request, modal-dialog

In my Laravel application (Bootstrap 4, jQuery and Axios) I have a page with multiple forms. Some forms are in a modal, but not all forms.

```
<form method="post">
<div class="modal">
// show errors
// form fields
</div>
</form>
```

I will not use ajax for posting this form. What is the best practice to show errors in a modal, when post a form when there are many others forms on the same page?

The problem now is: when a user posts a form with a field error, Laravel redirects the user back to the page, with the modal closed. When the user opens the modal, he shees the error in the modal.
What is the best practice to prevent this?

Comment: open the modal for him in the presence of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I have dealt with this in the past is to wrap some JS that executes on load inside some PHP conditional.

For example:

```html
@if($errors->has('field-in-modal'))
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
@endif
```

In laravel > 5.8.13:

```html
@error('field-in-modal')
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
@enderror
```

Then when you are redirected back with errors, you can open your modal immediately.

In the case where you have many fields under validation and checking each one is not a realistic option, I would suggest using a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation) or [manually creating the validator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) and using an after hook to add an error you might use as the flag:

```php
$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $validator->errors()->add('show-modal', 'use as a flag to show modal on pageload');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i add a field 'field-in-modal' to my custom errors?

Comment: The error will be in the `$errors` variable if you are using Laravel's built in validation. If you're not, just use the same check you use to display the errors in your modal. Without seeing more code, I can't be much more help.

Comment: I use the default Laravel validation, so I use as example this in my controller: $this->validate($request, ['title_in_modal', 'required']. This return a ViewErrorBag model. How can I get a 'field-in-modal' as return value

Comment: use your field - `title_in_modal` like `@error('title_in_modal')`

Comment: ah i understund, but i have long forms with 50 fields, then it is not a good solution...

Comment: Maybe explain more of your problem in the post so people who come to answer can help you better. Adding the controller code with validation rules etc. would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208588/discussion-between-angelique000-and-bryan).